# PHP | Passing parameters into Powershell script

Tags: php, shell, powershell, active-directory

I am trying to create a PHP application which runs powershell scripts.

I have a file called "change.ps1" which is a powershell script, here is the content of that file:

```
Param([string]$username, [string]$password)
Import-Module ActiveDirectory
$newpwd = ConvertTo-SecureString -String "$password" -AsPlainText –Force
Set-ADAccountPassword $username -NewPassword $newpwd –Reset
```

Now i have a PHP page which uses the shell_exec() function to run this script and pass TWO parameters to it, which you can see above is used in the ps1 file ( $username, $password):

```
    $psscriptpath = "c:\inetpub\htdocsscripts\change.ps1";
shell_exec("powershell.exe -executionpolicy remotesigned -File" . $psscriptpath . " -username \"" . $username . "\" -password \"" . $password . "\"");
```

At the moment this does not work (the page never finishes loading aka times out). So the question is, am i doing this correctly? where have i gone wrong. The theory behind this is relatively simple, use PHP to pass variables through as parameters into a powershell script.

Thanks for taking a look, and let me know if you have questions.

**UPDATE:**
I tried running the script directly via the cmd to see if the problem was in the script its self. Here is the error i was shown:
http://puu.sh/aXuH3/b8db154625.png

**SECOND UPDATE:**
I have fixed the error on the CMD, it was an encoding issue. However when i try to run the php page, i still get the time out issue:
http://puu.sh/aXEdY/22cc87310c.png

Comment: There's not enough info to help here, I will say this, though: [escape the arguments](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.escapeshellarg.php), and [the command](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.escapeshellcmd.php) properly

Comment: Okay so please ask for what info you need and i will gladly try and tell you.

Comment: what path is `change.ps1` stored in, in relation to the PHP code? you're using the relative path `scripts/change.ps1`, is this even correct. Have you tried replacing the `/` path separator with \\? is the script being run by a user that has the required rights to execute the powershell code? Can that user run powershell.exe? are you getting errors? if so, what messages are you seeing? For this last thing: try using the `exec` function, catch the full output, and the status code for more info

Comment: @EliasVanOotegem Yes, the path is correct. I can actually run powershell and run the command manually, so i would assume permissions is not the issue?

Comment: Also, i would like to add that i tried to run it directly via CMD to try and see if the script its self is correct. and i came across this error which was returned via cmd.exe: http://puu.sh/aXuH3/b8db154625.png

Comment: Running the script manually is one thing, that's your user who's running the script. But the user/process (don't know the windows lingo) might not be allowed to run powershell, in which case, it can't do its job. It might not be allowed to execute your script, in which case: chmod +x is in order... there's just too many system-specific variables to consider

Comment: Any ideas on the error message from CMD?

Comment: No, not really... like I said, it's been years since I've worked on a windows machine. I think it's been 2 years since I last touched powershell, so I really don't know... possibly an encoding issue (powershell is, I believe UTF-16 by default, PHP is UTF-8, and possibly on windows, limited to the ASCII subset, though I could be wrong here on all levels

Comment: Any usefull info in the PHP error log?

Comment: @Kayasax No not really.

Comment: PHP may launch the 32 bits version of powershell. Please verify the exécution policy in powershell 32bits

Comment: also, did you try to run it via command-line php? it doesn't make much sense to complicate things with CGI and IIS right from the start

Comment: @JimiDini As i have stated in my thread, it is fine in Command line

Comment: @Kayasax Can you please provide information on how to do the things you advise..

Comment: @user3714214 you misunderstood my question. I didn't mean running powershell script directly, but running php-script directly

Comment: @JimiDini Not sure what you mean. I have used command prompt to launch the script using powershell. What do you mean php-script directly

Comment: I mean run: "php.exe script.php" where script.php has just the essence of what you're trying to do (like example you gave above)

Comment: @user3714214 to launch the 32bits version of powershell : `%windir%\SysWOW64\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\powershell.exe` the type `get-executionpolicy`

Comment: I get the reply "restricted" when i type that.

Comment: @JimiDini Didnt seem to work, no errors or anything were returned and the password did not change.

Comment: @user3714214 you are not authorised to run scripts. lauch the 32bits version as administrator and type `set-executionpolicy unrestricted` (or remotesigned) see http://technet.microsoft.com/library/dd347641.aspx

Comment: I have done this, now i can run the script via CMD by running it through PHP, but in the browser aka cgi it still times out.

Answer (score 0):

ok, seems you are missing something.

1. you need to point to the absolute path of the script. If you saw my message on wizpert, i did a cd command to the directory of the script to ensure the correct environment:

   c:\>cd c:\my\directory\with\powershells

then you can execute your powershell with all the variables on it. Also try to do it via cmd to see if it produces any messages. If you see there is a timeout, it means that the process or is hanging or the web user does not have enough rights to execute shells.

If so, modify your php.ini or whatever let it know that the www-data user (in apache, not sure on IIS) has rights to execute commands.\

also it could be that you are executing that parameter wrongfully:

```
Param([string]$username, [string]$password)
Import-Module ActiveDirectory
$newpwd = ConvertTo-SecureString -String $password -AsPlainText –Force 
Set-ADAccountPassword $username -NewPassword $newpwd –Reset
```

Make $password without quotes on the powerscript.

Comment: I have tried to do this in IIS but with no luck, i am also confident it is something wrong with permissions/rights. Mabey you can help me via skype? borna.aslimand is my skype.

Answer (score 0):

### This is a solution for Windows 2012R2 server - Apache 2.4 - PHP 7.4

The trick is to switch the codepage in the command environment. Below shows that UTF is well revieved inside the ps1 file, since the content of the `test.txt` holds the correct data.

The problem arise, when the output from PowerShell goes back to the server encoded in codepage 850.

#### A change to codepage 65001 (UTF8) is the solution.

This is test.ps1

```
param([String]$p1)
$loc = $env:LOCALAPPDATA
"a${p1}b" | Out-File -FilePath "${loc}\test.txt" -Encoding utf8
chcp
chcp 65001
write-host "a${p1}b"
chcp 850
```

This is output from CDM.EXE

```
C:\PowerShell>powershell -file test.ps1 -p1 ÆØŁódźÅ€
Active code page: 850
Active code page: 65001
aÆØŁódźÅ€b
Active code page: 850
```

This is PHP

```
echo "<pre>";
$psscriptpath = "C:/powershell/test.ps1 -p1 ÆØŁódźÅ€";
echo $psscriptpath . '<br>';
echo 'From PowerShell:<br>';
$psData = shell_exec("powershell.exe -executionpolicy remotesigned -File " . $psscriptpath);
echo $psData . '<br>';
echo 'From readfile: ';
readfile(getenv('LOCALAPPDATA') . "\\test.txt");
echo "</pre>";
```

This is from my browser:

```
C:/powershell/test.ps1 -p1 ÆØŁódźÅ€
From PowerShell:
Active code page: 850
Active code page: 65001
aÆØŁódźÅ€b
Active code page: 850

From readfile: ﻿aÆØŁódźÅ€b
```

A final comment: Always switch back to you localized codepage after the data has been generated from some application.

I have experienced stange things to hanppend in the CMD window when it is in `65001 mode`

This trick also works when using the PostgreSQl `psql.exe` to output data. I assume the same goes for Mysql and others.