# Get-ADObject is not working in php

Tags: php, powershell

I am trying to query GC through PHP. I am just running simple test query. But it is not running with get-adobject. but if i use get-aduser i can get the result. it is weird. Even very simple get-adobject query is not working. For example below.

```
$user="xyzabc";
$queryfilter="\"samaccountname=$user\"";
$cmd='powershell "Get-ADObject -LDAPFilter ('.$queryfilter.') –Server abc1.xyz.com:3268"';
```

Then i am running exec($cmd) which is not giving any results/error. it is weird that even if i hardcode the variable still is not working or giving any error. I have run many other powershell queries using exec without any issues. But this get-adobject gives me hard time. can someone please help me.

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
Get-ADObject -LDAPFilter "(SamAccountName =$user)"
```

or use DN or GUID

Comment: `$cmd='powershell "Get-ADObject -LDAPFilter "(samaccountname =$user)" –Server abc1.xyz.com:3268"';

$output=exec($cmd);`   it didnt work. i tried as `$cmd='powershell "Get-ADObject -LDAPFilter \"(samaccountname =$user)\" –Server abc1.xyz.com:3268"';` still no luck. The actual working powershell query is `Get-ADObject -LDAPFilter ('samaccountname=user1234') –Server abc1.xyz.com:3268`

Answer (score 0):

Full disclosure - I am not a php guy, so I have never tried to use PoSH from PHP. So, see this post on PHP and PowerShell

[PHP | Passing parameters into Powershell script](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25361268/php-passing-parameters-into-powershell-script)

What are you trying to achieve by using Get-ADObject on a user, when Get-ADUser gets you all the user information?

Even the Get-ADObject docs specifically call out, for getting user object and info, to use the GetADUser cmdlet.

https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee617198.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396

You are using a quoted parenthetical string, and thus not getting the expansion of the variable you'd expect.

Secondly the $cmd is just going to have the result of the operation.

Examples runs from my test lab

```
Get-ADObject -LDAPFilter ('samaccountname=Administrator') –Server DC01


DistinguishedName                      Name...

CN=Administrator,CN=Users,DC=sateam... Administrator...


Get-ADObject -LDAPFilter "(samaccountname=$User)" –Server DC01


Get-ADObject : The search filter cannot be recognized
At line:1 char:1
+ Get-ADObject -LDAPFilter "(samaccountname=$User)" –Server DC01
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [Get-ADObject], ADException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : ActiveDirectoryServer:8254,Microsoft.ActiveDirectory.Management.Commands.GetADObject


$User = 'Administrator'
Get-ADObject -LDAPFilter ("samaccountname=$user") –Server DC01

DistinguishedName                      Name...

CN=Administrator,CN=Users,DC=sateam... Administrator...



powershell Get-ADObject -LDAPFilter ("samaccountname=$user") –Server DC01

Check user role
Current user - Administrator is running as a local Administrator
Check PowerShell Execution Policy
Unrestricted

DistinguishedName                      Name...

CN=Administrator,CN=Users,DC=sateam... Administrator...


$cmd = powershell Get-ADObject -LDAPFilter ("samaccountname=$user") –Server DC01
$cmd

Check user role
Current user - Administrator is running as a local Administrator
Check PowerShell Execution Policy
Unrestricted

DistinguishedName                      Name...

CN=Administrator,CN=Users,DC=sateam... Administrator...
```

If you are trying to construct a cmd string, the approach is the same

PS C:\Scripts> $User = 'Administrator'

```
PS C:\Scripts> $cmd = 'powershell Get-ADObject -LDAPFilter ("samaccountname=$user") –Server DC01'

PS C:\Scripts> $cmd   This will not run the above, it will just output it
powershell Get-ADObject -LDAPFilter ("samaccountname=$user") –Server DC01

PS C:\Scripts> &$cmd  this will run the above but will error because you are shelling out to the powershell console 
                      and that user variable has no meaning unless you have a way in php to pass it, and having powershell recognize how to run what you sent it.

& : The term 'powershell Get-ADObject -LDAPFilter ("samaccountname=$user") –Server DC01' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, function, 
script file, or operable program. Check the spelling of the name, or if a path was included, verify that the path is correct and try again.
At line:1 char:2
+ &$cmd  this will run the above but will error because you are shelling out to t ...
+  ~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : ObjectNotFound: (powershell Get-...Server DC01:String) [], CommandNotFoundException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : CommandNotFoundException


$Error | Format-List -Force

Exception             : System.Management.Automation.CommandNotFoundException: The term 'powershell Get-ADObject -LDAPFilter ("samaccountname=$user") 
                        –Server DC01' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, function, script file, or operable program. Check the spelling of 
                        the name, or if a path was included, verify that the path is correct and try again.
                           at System.Management.Automation.CommandDiscovery.LookupCommandInfo(String commandName, CommandTypes commandTypes, 
                        SearchResolutionOptions searchResolutionOptions, CommandOrigin commandOrigin, ExecutionContext context)
                           at System.Management.Automation.CommandDiscovery.LookupCommandProcessor(String commandName, CommandOrigin commandOrigin, 
                        Nullable`1 useLocalScope)
                           at System.Management.Automation.ExecutionContext.CreateCommand(String command, Boolean dotSource)
                           at System.Management.Automation.PipelineOps.AddCommand(PipelineProcessor pipe, CommandParameterInternal[] commandElements, 
                        CommandBaseAst commandBaseAst, CommandRedirection[] redirections, ExecutionContext context)
                           at System.Management.Automation.PipelineOps.InvokePipeline(Object input, Boolean ignoreInput, CommandParameterInternal[][] 
                        pipeElements, CommandBaseAst[] pipeElementAsts, CommandRedirection[][] commandRedirections, FunctionContext funcContext)
                           at System.Management.Automation.Interpreter.ActionCallInstruction`6.Run(InterpretedFrame frame)
                           at System.Management.Automation.Interpreter.EnterTryCatchFinallyInstruction.Run(InterpretedFrame frame)
TargetObject          : powershell Get-ADObject -LDAPFilter ("samaccountname=$user") –Server DC01
CategoryInfo          : ObjectNotFound: (powershell Get-...Server DC01:String) [], CommandNotFoundException
FullyQualifiedErrorId : CommandNotFoundException
ErrorDetails          : 
InvocationInfo        : System.Management.Automation.InvocationInfo
ScriptStackTrace      : at <ScriptBlock>, <No file>: line 1
PipelineIterationInfo : {}
PSMessageDetails      :
```